# Why does 'with' mean 'against' and not 'alongside' in phrases of opposition?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, etymology

In phrases like *fight with*, *argue with*, *combat with* etc, why does *with* mean the subject is opposing the object (grammatical object, technically a human opponent)?

Phrases like *go with*, *study with*, etc do not have such a meaning (as the acts have no opposing sides by their nature) and they mean the act is performed along with the other person.

How did *with* develop such a conflicting dual purpose?

Comment: I don't know about *why,* but *how* this occurred is summarized at [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php), where you can look up "with." Or get access to an OED, such as through a pulic library, for more details.

Comment: @ADTC I incorporated my comment into the answer now that it's been migrated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A brief diachronic analysis

It descends from Proto-Germanic **withro* (corresponding to Modern German *wider* 'against'), but took on additional meanings in Middle English when it replaced the now-obsolete *mid*, descended from Proto-Germanic **midi* (corresponding to Modern German *mit* 'with').  Since it now appears both with and without oppositional meaning, in Modern English it makes sense to assign any oppositional meaning to the verb it appears with rather than the preposition itself.

---

### A synchronic analysis

In your examples the preposition *with* is **comitative**, indicating that at least two participants together play the same semantic role.  In the case of *fight with*, for example, it indicates that both participants are fighting.

However, the oppositional meaning comes from *fight*, not from *with*.

Take a look at this example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companions_of_William_the_Conqueror):

> The term “**Companions of the Conqueror**” in the widest sense signifies those who planned, organised and joined with William the Conqueror, Duke of Normandy, in the great adventure which was the Norman Conquest of England (1066–1071). The term is however more narrowly defined as **those nobles who actually fought with Duke William** in the Battle of Hastings.

Here, the nobles were companions of the Duke.  They were fighting alongside him, not against him.  Despite this, *fight with* is appropriate.  In this example, the object of *with* isn't in opposition to the phrase it modifies.

Sometimes, though, it is:

> I **fought with** my sister today.

Here, my sister and I are the only two participants.  Since the semantics of *fight* require two opposing sides, there's no way we could have fought on the same side―we naturally understand that my sister and I were on opposing sides when I say this sentence.  Any other interpretation is unlikely (unless we have some additional context to suggest there were other participants).

The same thing isn't true of the Battle of Hastings, which had far more than two participants.  The semantics of *fight* don't require that the opposing side is specified using *with*, they only require that an opposing side exists.  This allows us to interpret *fight with* as meaning "fight alongside" in the Hastings example.

Verbs like *study* and *go* are different:

> I **studied with** my sister today.

These verbs have no semantic requirement for opposition, so naturally phrases like *study with* lack any oppositional meaning.  The preposition itself no longer carries this meaning.

Comment: In the last para do you mean "have **no** semantic requirement"?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you see in the preposition with is a difference of the verbs. The idea of opposition is exclusively expressed by the verbs.